# Should `.yarn/releases` be checked in when using `yarn policies`?

Tags: yarnpkg

I was looking at https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/policies/ and it seems like a good idea to use it to allow my team to easily be on the same yarn version. However, `yarn policies set 1.18` downloads the full yarn release into `.yarn/releases` (a 4.5mb js file) and sets a config entry in the repo's `.yarnrc` file.

It feels weird to check in this 4.5mb yarn executable, but if I don't, my colleagues are not going to be able to run yarn, because the entry in the `.yarnrc` won't exist on their system and it's not magically downloaded...

So, is it best practice to check the `.yarn/releases` folder into version control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your assumption is correct, you check yarnrc and the actual yarn JS file into source control.